# How to download segmented videos from a url

Tags: google-chrome, video, download, file-download, cdn

I am trying to download videos from a url using google chrome. In developer tools under network, I see video segments like

```
https://videodelivery.net/cd6ff47b2a3bedc1edc1e8a7c92c1297/video/720/seg_45.mp4?p=eyJ0eXBlIjoic2VnbWVudCIsInZpZGVvSUQiOiJjZDZmZjQ3YjJhM2JlZGMxZWRjMWU4YTdjOTJjMTI5NyIsInRyYWNrIjoiYzkyNzVhOTY1YTI5Njk0YjVjNGRiNjA2MDE5NDE2NzEiLCJyZW5kaXRpb24iOiIyMTIwMDc0NCIsIm11eGluZyI6IjQyMzc3MzI1In0&s=wqJnBA5Nw6RTw4IFwr96w4rCosKfcBp3G8Oow6p-LsK4VggAM3huUkti



https://videodelivery.net/cd6ff47b2a3bedc1edc1e8a7c92c1297/video/720/seg_46.mp4?p=eyJ0eXBlIjoic2VnbWVudCIsInZpZGVvSUQiOiJjZDZmZjQ3YjJhM2JlZGMxZWRjMWU4YTdjOTJjMTI5NyIsInRyYWNrIjoiYzkyNzVhOTY1YTI5Njk0YjVjNGRiNjA2MDE5NDE2NzEiLCJyZW5kaXRpb24iOiIyMTIwMDc0NCIsIm11eGluZyI6IjQyMzc3MzI1In0&s=wqJnBA5Nw6RTw4IFwr96w4rCosKfcBp3G8Oow6p-LsK4VggAM3huUkti
```

When I copy and paste any of the above in the browser, I see blank video screen of 0 seconds as shown below

[image: Blank video]

How to assemble such video segments to get the original video?

Comment: If this is a CMAF stream using fMP4, you may also need to concatenate the initialization file (advertised in #EXT-X-MAP:URI for HLS or initialization for DASH) to the beginning of your other segments.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to just simply concatenate the files after downloading individually.  Try it with the first two segments and if it works, it'll probably work with every segment.

Under Windows, you can do this:

`copy seg_1.mp4 /b + seg_2.mp4 /b combined.mp4`

or Linux/Mac/other Unix:

`cat seg_1.mp4 seg_2.mp4 > combined.mp4`